# UI Router- stateChangeStart fires like 50 times

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

**UPDATE**: I added a console statement, and it seems that this listener handler is invoked like 50 times for this one event. Or it can be said that this event is firing like 50 times. Any idea why? What can be done?

**FIX UPDATE**:

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer").run(function($rootScope, $state, DeviceVal){
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){
    if (DeviceVal.readonly && toState.name == "main.loadbalancer.vips") {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.transitionTo("main.loadbalancer.readonly",  {id: "534584"});
        console.log(toState);
    }
  });
});
```

---

Whenever `$state.transitionTo("main.loadbalancer.readonly");` is ran I get a `UI Router: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Not sure where or what to do.

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer").run(function($rootScope, $state, DeviceVal){
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event){
    if (DeviceVal.readonly) {
        $state.transitionTo("main.loadbalancer.readonly");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

---

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer", ["ui.bootstrap", "ui.router"]).config(function($stateProvider) {
  return $stateProvider.state("main.loadbalancer", {
    resolve: {
      waitForDeviceId: function($state, $q, $timeout, DeviceVal) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function() {
          if (DeviceVal.lb) {
            deferred.resolve();
          } else {
            deferred.reject();
          }
        }, 1000);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    },
    url: "device/:id",
    views: {
      "content@": {
        templateUrl: "loadbalancer/loadbalancer.html",
        controller: "LoadBalancerCtrl"
      }
    }
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.vips", {
    url: "/vips",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/vip-table.html",
    controller: "VipListCtrl"
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.nodes", {
    url: "/nodes",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/node-table.html",
    controller: "NodeListCtrl"
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.admin", {
    url: "/admin",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/admin.html",
    controller: "AdminCtrl"
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.readonly", {
    url: "/readonly",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/readonly.html"
  });
});
```

---

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at http://10.14.213.161:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7004:18
    at Scope.$broadcast (http://10.14.213.161:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12456:15)
    at Object.transitionTo (http://10.14.213.161:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2032:26)
    at http://10.14.213.161:9000/loadbalancer/services/readonly.service.js:4:16
    at Scope.$broadcast (http://10.14.213.161:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12454:28)
    at Object.transitionTo (http://10.14.213.161:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2032:26)
    at http://10.14.213.161:9000/loadbalancer/services/readonly.service.js:4:16
    at Scope.$broadcast (http://10.14.213.161:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12454:28)
    at Object.transitionTo (http://10.14.213.161:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2032:26)
    at http://10.14.213.161:9000/loadbalancer/services/readonly.service.js:4:16
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that you are transitioning in your event handler. This is causing an infinite loop.  Instead, you need to explicitly avoid broadcasting the $stateChangeStart when inside of your handler.  You can use the `notify:false` flag to do this.  Try this instead:

```
$state.transitionTo("main.loadbalancer.readonly", null, {notify:false});
```

You can also read the [complete API docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But somehow it keeps `notify:false` keeps the state transition from running.

Comment: Where are you putting `notify:false`? Is it inside the event handler?  Can you pose your changed code, because this doesn't make sense.

Comment: update complete. I am using `{id: "534584"}` just for temp. problem solving. Also, the toState shows `Object {url: "/vips", templateUrl: "loadbalancer/vip-table.html", controller: "VipListCtrl", name: "main.loadbalancer.vips"} `

Comment: Actually, I found a different way...will post up on top. But thanks, your root cause was correct which lead me to this fix.